# How can I see queries to gpg-agent?

Tags: monitoring, gpg, notifications, gpg-agent, yubikey

I am using gpg-agent together with a Yubikey to securely store my GPG keys. In addition I've enabled so that whenever a authentication, sign or decryption request happens I must physically push the button on the Yubikey. It is very clear when I do `ssh FOO` and the Yubikey starts blinking that I need to push it.

I also have cron jobs that perform things, like running mbsync in the background to retrieve email and they in turn use GPG to decrypt the file containing the password. In this case I haven't interactively initiated the command but instead my Yubikey just starts blinking and I don't know why (although I can guess). I would like to be able to see what the current query to gpg-agent is.

Is there a way I can monitor and display the queries to gpg-agent so I can see what the current query is actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your gpg-agent.conf (in your home directory):

```
--log-file <filename>
```